# Random image javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, random, generate

I am struggling a bit with this random image javascript even though I sense the answer is quite simple. My code generates four letters (images) at a time. How do I get the code to regenerate new letters instead of adding four additional letters (images)?

Here is a  [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vb68fghw/2/) also.

```
  <script>
function getRandomImage() {
//declare an array to store the images
var randomImage = new Array();

//insert the URL of images in array
randomImage[0] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/a.png";
randomImage[1] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/b.png";
randomImage[2] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/c.png";
randomImage[3] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/d.png";
randomImage[4] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/e.png";
randomImage[5] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/f.png";
randomImage[6] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/g.png";
randomImage[7] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/h.png";
randomImage[8] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/i.png";
randomImage[9] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/j.png";
randomImage[10] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/k.png";
randomImage[11] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/l.png";
randomImage[12] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/m.png";
randomImage[13] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/n.png";
randomImage[14] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/o.png";
randomImage[15] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/p.png";
randomImage[16] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/q.png";
randomImage[17] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/r.png";
randomImage[18] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/s.png";
randomImage[19] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/t.png";
randomImage[20] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/u.png";
randomImage[21] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/v.png";
randomImage[22] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/w.png";
randomImage[23] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/x.png";
randomImage[24] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/y.png";
randomImage[25] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/z.png";
//loop to display five randomly chosen images at once
for (let i=0; i< 4; i++) {
//generate a number and provide to the image to generate randomly
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.length);
//print the images generated by a random number
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += '<img src="'+ randomImage[number] +'" style="height:150px";/>';
}
}

</script>
<body>
<h1> GENERATE YOUR LETTERS... </h1>
<!-- call user-defined getRandomImage function to generate image -->  
<center><button onclick = "getRandomImage()" class="btn btn-white btn-        animate">Let's Go!</button></center>
<br> <br>
<span id="result" align="center"> </span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ""` before your for loop to clear the result div before adding 4 new items.

You can also reduce your code a lot by using a for loop to generate the image URLs.

```
var letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');

for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    randomImage.push(`http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/${letters[i]}.png`)
}
```

Comment: Can you add that to my code? Should I replace all the urls with your "var letters"? Sorry JS confuses me still

Comment: Yes, here's a working forked example of your JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/s29h8q5w/

Comment: You could write this even shorter as `const randomImage = Array.from('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz').map(letter => \`http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/${letter}.png\`);`

Answer (score 1):

**document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = " " before  for loop**

```
    <script>
function getRandomImage() {
//declare an array to store the images
var randomImage = new Array();

//insert the URL of images in array
randomImage[0] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/a.png";
randomImage[1] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/b.png";
randomImage[2] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/c.png";
randomImage[3] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/d.png";
randomImage[4] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/e.png";
randomImage[5] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/f.png";
randomImage[6] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/g.png";
randomImage[7] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/h.png";
randomImage[8] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/i.png";
randomImage[9] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/j.png";
randomImage[10] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/k.png";
randomImage[11] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/l.png";
randomImage[12] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/m.png";
randomImage[13] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/n.png";
randomImage[14] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/o.png";
randomImage[15] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/p.png";
randomImage[16] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/q.png";
randomImage[17] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/r.png";
randomImage[18] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/s.png";
randomImage[19] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/t.png";
randomImage[20] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/u.png";
randomImage[21] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/v.png";
randomImage[22] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/w.png";
randomImage[23] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/x.png";
randomImage[24] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/y.png";
randomImage[25] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/z.png";
//loop to display five randomly chosen images at once
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
for (let i=0; i< 4; i++) {
//generate a number and provide to the image to generate randomly
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.length);
//print the images generated by a random number

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += '<img src="'+ randomImage[number] +'" style="height:150px";/>';
}
}

</script>
<body>
<h1> GENERATE YOUR LETTERS... </h1>
<!-- call user-defined getRandomImage function to generate image -->  
<center><button onclick = "getRandomImage()" class="btn btn-white btn-        animate">Let's Go!</button></center>
<br> <br>
<span id="result" align="center"> </span>
```

Comment: before loop you have to add document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
for (let i=0; i< 4; i++) {

Answer (score 0):

Add following code at starting of the function definition :

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
```

Like this

```
<script>
function getRandomImage() {

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";

//declare an array to store the images
var randomImage = new Array();

//insert the URL of images in array
randomImage[0] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/a.png";
randomImage[1] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/b.png";
randomImage[2] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/c.png";
randomImage[3] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/d.png";
randomImage[4] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/e.png";
randomImage[5] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/f.png";
randomImage[6] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/g.png";
randomImage[7] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/h.png";
randomImage[8] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/i.png";
randomImage[9] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/j.png";
randomImage[10] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/k.png";
randomImage[11] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/l.png";
randomImage[12] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/m.png";
randomImage[13] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/n.png";
randomImage[14] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/o.png";
randomImage[15] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/p.png";
randomImage[16] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/q.png";
randomImage[17] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/r.png";
randomImage[18] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/s.png";
randomImage[19] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/t.png";
randomImage[20] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/u.png";
randomImage[21] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/v.png";
randomImage[22] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/w.png";
randomImage[23] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/x.png";
randomImage[24] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/y.png";
randomImage[25] = "http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/z.png";
//loop to display five randomly chosen images at once
for (let i=0; i< 4; i++) {
//generate a number and provide to the image to generate randomly
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.length);
//print the images generated by a random number
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += '<img src="'+ randomImage[number] +'" style="height:150px";/>';
}
}

</script>
<body>
<h1> GENERATE YOUR LETTERS... </h1>
<!-- call user-defined getRandomImage function to generate image -->  
<center><button onclick = "getRandomImage()" class="btn btn-white btn-        animate">Let's Go!</button></center>
<br> <br>
<span id="result" align="center"> </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in ["innerHTML += ..." vs "appendChild(txtNode)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode) appending new elements by doing `innerHTML += '<img />'` causes the browser to rebuild the entire container. This may cause performance issues depending on where, when and how often you call it. For the sake of completeness I'm providing the more performant example (a bit more verbose but in general better practice).

This should replace your `for` loop:

```
// Clear all childs from the container

const container = document.getElementById("result");
container.childNodes.forEach((child) => child.remove());

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImage.length);

  // Create a new <img /> element and append it to the container

  const image = document.createElement("img");
  image.src = randomImage[number];
  image.style.height = "150px";
  container.append(image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get a random letter without splitting a string by using the method given in the top voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505419/choosing-a-random-letter-from-a-z). You can then simplify your code as the others have mentioned above to only a few lines.

I've commented the code below.

---

```js
// Function triggered with onclick event
function getRandomImage() {

  // Clear the previous letters
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";

  // Loop
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    // Generate random letter
    letter = String.fromCharCode(97 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26))

    // Add image to #result
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += '<img src="http://www.englishclass.dk/_themes/englishclass/img/scrabble/' + letter + '.png" style="height:150px";/>';

  }

}
```

```html
  <h1> GENERATE YOUR LETTERS... </h1>
  <center>
    <button onclick="getRandomImage()" class class="btn btn-white btn-animate">
      Let's Go!
    </button>
  </center>
  <br>
  <br>
 <span id="result" align="center"> </span>
```